# at-rule or selector expected using tailwind

Tags: vue.js, sass, tailwind-css, vite

I have the following scss file:

```
@import "tailwind/base";
@import "tailwind/components";
@import "tailwind/utilities";

@import "scrollbars";
@import "fonts";

body {
  @apply font-regular #{!important};
}
```

And on the closing tag of the `body` im getting `at-rule or selector expectedscss(css-ruleorselectorexpected)`. Im using the special important syntax tailwind recommends so im kind of at a loss as to why this is happening

Comment: If you are getting the `at-rule or selector expectedscss(css-ruleorselectorexpected)` message in VSCode, then you can safely ignore it. The message appears in VSCode as its CSS parser does not understand `@apply`.

Comment: I'm getting `Unknown at rule @applyscss(unknownAtRules)` for the `apply`, seperately.

Comment: @Wongjn, yes we can, but Prettier mark this as error and do confused analitics